# Image warping by means of a vector field using Python

Tags: python, opencv, opengl, image-processing, interpolation

I have two images of the same size and I have computed a vector field to warp the second image onto the first one.

However, as my vector field is computed over a grid with a 10 pixels spacing along both directions, I would like to define such a vector field but for all points of my image.

Thus, I am wondering how I could achieve this.

Comment: well, if you computed the vector field why don't you compute it denser?

Comment: Because it much more slower .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities:

- interpolate between the points - 2D interpolation over regular grid,
  should be fast, using [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.ev.html)
- compute your vector field for a 1-pixel resolution
- reduce the size (using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm)) of your original image    and use the
  10-pixel vector field

Either case it is a tradeoff between image size/quality and speed.

Comment: I am indeed trying to perform 2D interpolation using scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline but I am facing some difficulty to understand how it really works.